# How to suppress specific log output of maven git-commit-id-maven-plugin plugin?

Tags: maven, logging

Problem, we use v4.9 of [git-commit-id-maven-plugin](https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin)

Log output for `[INFO] Tag refs` is huge, about 2-4 screens

`[INFO] --- git-commit-id:4.9.10:revision (default) @ server ---`  
....
`[INFO] Tag refs [[Ref[refs/tags/1.0.1=3254ae156395007f2805cca386f4b2d65483ceb1(-1)], Ref[refs/tags/5.0.4=14f9d127049117fec941d85dba2c765076762ce6(-1)], Ref[refs/tags/8.8.12=8605346b6e5a49d592b6aab887eb1ed5c5c2aaeb(-1)], Ref[refs/tags/banking-redirect-testing=379a21743cca4465e2eb5f3968f00535a2be534b(-1)], Ref[refs/tags/deploy-postfach-stage20201104=7bbc0efb1e5494bbb95df1a7de6fae5a73e5cbb1(-1)], Ref[refs/tags/deploy-postfach-stage20201210=154f7844665a26ab9f26976a03e8d08ed2c1cd86(-1)], Ref[refs/tags/deploy-rzwwi-test-fgstage=7ef1e17eddd21b361853f4de7620528b4b2a484c(-1)], Ref[refs/tags/experiment/TF-5080-baxit-worker-refreshlogic=8dd3fa54131a33d52e20c892375c76476667bc18(-1)], Ref[refs/tags/experiment/TF...`

How to suppress specific log output of maven this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Went with verbose=false for the plugin,

```xml
                <configuration>
                    ...
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
```

That actually completely supresses normal output.

So just

```
[INFO] --- git-commit-id:4.9.10:revision (default) @ module ---
[INFO]
```

See sources, Luke
https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/pl/project13/maven/git/GitCommitIdMojo.java#L127-L146